# App on the SIM card of a GSM mobile with NFC to connect to Android app

Tags: java, android, nfc, open-mobile-api, secure-element

We need to design a simple application which has to reside on the SIM card of a GSM mobile with NFC and should connect to an Android phone app. Is anyone able to provide a link on this? 
Until now we already have apps on Android but we need to connect to NFC on the SIM card or on the phone. How should we go about it? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The Open Mobile API may be what you are looking for. An Android implementation exists with the [SEEK-for-Android](https://code.google.com/p/seek-for-android/) project. However, SEEK is currently not integrated into main-line Android (AOSP) and consequently is not available on all devices. Note that both the hardware and vendor-specific software components need to support communication with a phone's UICC, so you can't just add support by packaging SEEK with your own app.

Comment: I have seen that you have done a lot of work regarding Open Mobile API, I am wondering if there is a way to detect whether the SIM card supports being used as a secure element in NFC transactions? Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score -2):

SIM card communication us done using ADPU (Application Protocol Data Units), which is a sequence of hexadecimal numbers. One communicate's with the SIM using HostApduService:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/cardemulation/HostApduService.html

Applications on the SIM are generally written in JavaCard (an OS which uses some Java syntax) but they can only be installed by the network operator who owns the SIM - getting the application installed will be harder than writing it.

Bill.

Comment: `HostApduService` on Android does not have anything to do with SIM card communication. The `HostApduService` is used to register Android applications (not the SIM card) for APDU communication with reader hardware over the NFC interface (again: not with SIM card). There is the `OffHostApduService` which is used to register SIM/UICC applications for communication over the NFC interface (but again: not for communication between Android apps and applications on the SIM/UICC).